# Xcode 9 not installing app on actual device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios11, xcode9

Hi I am new to iOS development, I installed Xcode 9 from MacAppStore and now trying to run my first app on my iPhone 6s but the issue is it runs well on the simulator but when I try to install it on the actual device the build fails, I also selected trust this computer form the pop up box after connecting it to Mac.
How to get this thing work.

[image]

In the Logs its displaying something what does that means.

Comment: Please add more info (logs, screenshots)

Comment: do you have a paid developer account ??

Comment: No I don't because now has allowed developer to install their app on actual device.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205250/1773867

Comment: @Kaushal you've to install new certificates in your mac and remove the certificates which are already installed.

Comment: @KaushalTopinkatti try clear derive data