# Xcode 9 - Alamofire Pods. Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire, xcode9

```
/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-ehabmnclpzlywhabrefntacibonm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Fuego/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//MyProject.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I got this issue when I Archive my project. When I run app on simulator it works ok without such issue above.

Also it works ok with `Xcode 8`, but now when I try to Archive it on `Xcode 9` I have this issue. But maybe this is not the case as I reinstall `Mac OS` from scratch, so it maybe cocopods version issue I am not sure.

Also two `//` here in the example above is also strange for me `/Applications//MyProject.app`

Comment: For any newer developers, programmers, or folks into experimenting with coding who might stumble across this exchange, as I did, I wanted to be specific and let you know that the signed certificate we're all talking about here can be created by way of referencing your xcode readme file, and following the instructions laid out there. Fortunately, for once (ahem...apple... smh) the instructions are concise, accurate, and easy to execute! The only tidbit I would add is that I would recommend not bothering with the legacy downloads they recommend. At this point, those legacy downloads (2005) are m

Answer (score 12):

I believe it's a Xcode's bug. Restart your Mac and try to build again. Xcode would ask permission to access your Keychain before build Alamofire, then just allow it.

Comment: This is actually correct. Mastrosov's answer has too many steps to follow :P Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. I was having similar issue. Xcode builds my project without any problem if I choose simulator. On device, it gives me the same error @Matrosov has posted. Restarting resolves the issue.

Comment: Solved my issue! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hm it's very strange after some search on the Web I found that this is actually signing issue.

I used Xcode to generate new distribution certificate and maybe this leads some problems for me.

What I did to solve my issue.

1. I removed all certificates on my Mac and in my apple account.
2. I removed all prov profiles as well on my Mac and in my apple account.
3. I requested certificate and save it on the disc manually (not via Xcode )
4. I recreated certificate and profile. Downloaded it manually and double click on it.
5. After that I faced with keychain issue when I can not enter password to allow signing my certificate. I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205250/swift-sdtlib-tool-error-task-failed-with-exit-code-1) to move certificate form login to system section.
6. Finally I get it work.