# xcode 9.3 error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire

After I cleaned my project and deleted the DerivedData files, I still have the error.

```
    mkdir -p /Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Cable Park/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Cable Park.app/Frameworks
    Symlinked...
    rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Cable Park/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" 
"/Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Cable Park/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Cable Park.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... done
    Alamofire.framework/
    Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
    Alamofire.framework/Info.plist

        sent 7644058 bytes  received 70 bytes  15288256.00 bytes/sec
        total size is 7642892  speedup is 1.00
        Code Signing /Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Cable Park/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Cable Park.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Geoffroy Hachez (YYNBZTVS5Q)
        /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 3EF707F7B9FBEB2A900A4FE19B59A6EA180661DD  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Cable Park/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Cable Park.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
        /Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Cable Park/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Cable Park.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
        Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I search for hour a solution, but I cannot archive my project.

---

(EDIT 1)
After a new clean, deleted derivedData and reboot.
this is the new message

```
mkdir -p /Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cable Park.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cable Park.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Alamofire.framework/
Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Alamofire.framework/Info.plist

sent 3254366 bytes  received 70 bytes  6508872.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3253736  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cable Park.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Geoffroy Hachez (YYNBZTVS5Q)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 3EF707F7B9FBEB2A900A4FE19B59A6EA180661DD  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cable Park.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/geoff/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cable_Park-bxyqeiprdndohveuzrnvtsybtjqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cable Park.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

---

(EDIT 2) I create a new project it's the same application. when I do simulator it works. When I do a compilation on my iPhone or archive, the same error come back.
Someone told me to remove the "//" but I don't know where to do that.
Please help me to resolve this, it's very frustrating
 Thanks

---

Answer (score 0):

The two “//“ next to each other in the path below looks suspicious

Between Applications and Cable Park

/Applications//Cable Park.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... done

Comment: I did not see where you see that.

Answer (score 0):

I find my issues.
it was certificat problem

I did this
[Xcode 9 - Alamofire Pods. Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617037/xcode-9-alamofire-pods-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-1)

and it work now.

Answer (score -1):

Try these steps:

1- Delete derived data

2 - Clean your Project

3- Restart your system

4- Build your project

Comment: thank you. I did all of this and it still not working

Comment: it's normal that alamofire.framworks is not the same color? it's more "whyte"?

Comment: try reinstalling or updating your pods

Comment: just did it, I post the message