# Shell script invocation error command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios

I'm getting shell script invocation error command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 error in Xcode 9.1.

Precisely it's working fine, but it's getting error...
I tried to delete derived data, but after that also it's getting error.
Can any one help me to solve this error...

```
mkdir -p /Users/developement/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App Name-elbnnhecajvuocajithvpcwntcof/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/App Name.app/Frameworks
rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/developement/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App Name-elbnnhecajvuocajithvpcwntcof/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/IQKeyboardManager/IQKeyboardManager.framework" "/Users/developement/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/elbnnhecajvuocajithvpcwntcof/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/App Name.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
IQKeyboardManager.framework/
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager
IQKeyboardManager.framework/Info.plist
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/IQButtonBarArrowDown@2x.png
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/IQButtonBarArrowDown@3x.png
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/IQButtonBarArrowLeft@2x.png
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/IQButtonBarArrowLeft@3x.png
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/IQButtonBarArrowRight@2x.png
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/IQButtonBarArrowRight@3x.png
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/IQButtonBarArrowUp@2x.png
IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager.bundle/IQButtonBarArrowUp@3x.png

sent 631432 bytes  received 252 bytes  1263368.00 bytes/sec
total size is 630553  speedup is 1.00

Code Signing /Users/developement/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App Name-elbnnhecajvuocajithvpcwntcof/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/App Name.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManager.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Developer ID
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 4A6D63EB1880BC5B617BFF614E2D009066DF1E  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/developement/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App Name-elbnnhecajvuocajithvpcwntcof/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/App Name.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManager.framework'
/Users/developement/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App Name-elbnnhecajvuocajithvpcwntcof/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/App Name.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManager.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I'm getting this error only when I run in device. If i run in simulator it's working fine.

Comment: But it's not working...

Comment: Delete derived data -> Quite XCode -> remove derived data from trash -> restart XCode. After this error should probably go.

Comment: Yes, I removed from trash folder and closed my Xcode. But it's getting error

Comment: Try step by step from my answer below.
Don't change the sequence while performing those steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case:

1. Clean Product
2. Clean Build Folder
3. Open derived data folder from Xcode
4. Quit XCode
5. Delete Derived data
6. Delete derived data from Trash as well
7. Open Xcode
8. Run your app

If this doesn't solve your problem, remove your account and add it again using below steps:

1. Open Preferences from XCode menu
2. Goto Accounts
3. Select your developer account under Apple IDs
4. Remove that account
5. Add your account back

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm using IQKeyboardManager, Crashlytics and google analytics.

Comment: Could you update your answer with few more details of the error? Or could you post the screenshot of the error screen?

Comment: Just want to be sure, Did follow my answer step by step in a given sequence?

Comment: I'm getting this error only when I run in device. If i run in simulator it's working fine.

Comment: Yeah, It will work fine with simulator because it doesn't require code signing.
Could you try answer by @kingfoot on below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230877/4988884

Give it a shot, I'm not sure if it will work in your case.

Comment: Finally, today it's working. After restarting our system. Thank u very much to spent your valuable time for me.... @Mohnish Hirudkar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160477/discussion-between-mohnish-hirudkar-and-ios-developer).