# run Xcode project on my iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I cannot figure out why Xcode does not allow me to run an Xcode project on my actual device (iPhone 6  version 11.3.1). I have uninstalled Xcode then reinstalled it multiple times. I have used different devices to test the projects but no success. When I test it on Simulators it works perfectly but not on my iPhone. Xcode gives me this error ":  Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {". I am using Xcode 9.3.1, I have an iOS team provisioning profile. I have not run a project on my actual device so I do not know if im missing something or there is set up required. I am not sure what is going on or how to solve this issue. your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: have you check with code signing certificate and registered device UUID?

Comment: Have you added device in iTunes connect?

Comment: Yes my device is registered and connected to iTunes

Comment: In the project navigator, select the project file (top most item), select your target, select _General_ in the menu above the targets, check the _Signing_ section for errors. Also click on the small info icon next to _Provisioning Profile_.

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205250/swift-sdtlib-tool-error-task-failed-with-exit-code-1

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to those who tried to help. 
After 3 days of going through this issue It worked. FINALLY!
Here is how it worked: 
Steps:
Select the top menu Xcode then select Preferences then Accounts. 
Select your account then select Download Manual Profiles. Wait until Download is complete then select the Manage Certificates...
This will open a new page. "Signing Certificates for "Your Account Name""
A list of all certificates will be displayed. 
At the bottom left of this page select the + and from the dropdown list select the Mac Development option. 
I then got a new Certificate.